# How can I animate the height of a modal that changes based on the type of content?

Tags: react-native, animation

I have a modal that changes heights based on a status string. The different heights work, but I'm trying to figure out how to smoothly animate in between the height transitions. Right now, I have a smooth transition from when the modal opens to the final height and when it closes, but when the modal changes height before fully closing it, there's no smooth animation to slide down.

Example:
When I click on a button, my modal animates to a height of 70.
Once I click on a button from inside the modal, my modal should animate smoothly to a height of 60.
Once I click on a button from inside my modal again, my modal should animate smoothly to a height of 40.

There's a smooth sliding up and down animation for the modal when I first open it and for when I fully close it, but not for the steps in between mentioned above.

```
export interface Props {
  expanded?: boolean;
  maxHeightPercentage?: number;
  onClose?: () => void;
  onOpen?: () => void;
  onOpened?: () => void;
  onClosed?: () => void;
}
export const Overlay: React.FC<Props> = ({
  expanded = false,
  onClose,
  onOpen,
  onClosed,
  onOpened,
  maxHeightPercentage = 67,
  children,
}) => {
  const [expandedInternal, setExpandedInternal] = useState(false);
  const previousExpandedInternal = usePrevious(expandedInternal);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (expanded !== expandedInternal) {
      setExpandedInternal(expanded);
    }
  }, [expanded, expandedInternal]);
  const theme = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const overlayHeight = useRef(new Animated.Value(0));
  useEffect(() => {
    if (expandedInternal !== previousExpandedInternal) {
      expandedInternal ? onOpen?.() : onClose?.();
      const callback = expandedInternal ? onOpened : onClosed;
      const toValue = expandedInternal ? 1 : 0;
      Animated.timing(overlayHeight.current, {
        toValue,
        duration: 500,
        easing: Easing.linear,
        useNativeDriver: false,
      }).start(callback);
    }
  }, [expandedInternal, onClose, onOpen, onOpened, onClosed, previousExpandedInternal]);
  return (
    <Animated.View
      style={
        {
          height: overlayHeight.current.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: ["0%", `${maxHeightPercentage}%`],
          }),
        },
      }>
      {children}
    </Animated.View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the [LayoutAnimation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/layoutanimation) API?

Comment: @Kai I haven't used it much, but I have heard of it! I'll take a look at that doc, thanks. By any chance do you know where I can see a simple example of this LayoutAnimation with a modal that changes height??

Comment: Also, I've heard about generally, the Animated API is preferred over the LayoutAnimation API, not sure if that's accurate though..